# How to use Vue.js with Requirejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have generated sample `Vue.js` project using `vue-cli` and built it by

```
vue build --target lib --name myWidget src/main.js
```

I must use `Requirejs` to load it:

```
    <script>
        requirejs.config({
            paths: {
                "Vue": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue",
                "myWidget": "https://codematic.tech/yamaWidget.umd",
            }
        });
    </script>
```

```
    <script>
        require(["Vue"], function (Vue) {
            console.log('Vue loaded');
            require(["myWidget"], function (widget) {
                console.log('Widget loaded');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Looks like it should work, however I've got an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```

which points to

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

in source code. I managed to fix it by adding `Vue = window.Vue;` in Vue's main.js file and `window.Vue = Vue` in `<script>` tag, after require'ing `Vue`.  Library is loading, mounting in `#app`. Looks weird, but is working.

Problem is when I import something in Vue's `main.js` file. In example, 
`import Snotify from 'vue-snotify';`
gives me an error below:

`Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined`

which leads me to line:

`var script = external_commonjs_vue_commonjs2_vue_root_Vue_default.a.extend({`

By the way - when I load both Vue.js and myWidget.umd.js directly through `<script>` tag, everything is working fine!

Comment: Might need the runtime + compiler build, here's a listing of all available: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Problem was external library `vue-snotify` which caused this issue.